# How to add an action when this button is clicked

Tags: html, angular

So I have this button code

```
<button class="card card-small" (click)="selection.value = 'download" tabindex="0">
  <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></svg>
  <span>Download</span>
</button>
```

How can i check if the button was clicked?

Im new to Html And Angular And i don't know

Comment: You're executing `selection.value = 'download`. In a similiar way, you could instead call a function inside of your component that executes this logic plus any additional logic you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add (click) event in button.

```
<button class="card card-small" (click)="clickFunction()" tabindex="0">
  <svg class="material-icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z"/></svg>
  <span>Download</span>
</button>
```

And you can check in console Button clicked or not.

```
clickFunction() {
    console.log('Button clicked!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I've already add it in Stackblitz, too. Check it out .

app.component.html

```
<button
  class="card card-small"
  (click)="onClick($event, 'download')"
  tabindex="0"
>
  <svg
    class="material-icons"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    width="24"
    height="24"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  >
    <path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z" />
  </svg>
  <span>Download</span>
</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  onClick($event, value: any) {
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-button-fhywhw?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]

Comment: it gaves me:
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:11:11 - error TS7006: Parameter '$event' implicitly has an 'any' type.

11   onClick($event, value) {
             ~~~~~~


Error: src/app/app.component.ts:11:19 - error TS7006: Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.

11   onClick($event, value) {
                     ~~~~~

Comment: Recheck it. I've updated. It need to declare like this => value: any

Answer (score 0):

```
export class TestComponent {
    showData($event: any){
        console.log("button is clicked!"); if($event) {
            console.log($event.target);
            console.log($event.target.value);
        }
    }
}


<button (click)="showData($event)">Click here</button>
Alternatively, you can use prefix - on using canonical form as shown below −
<button on-click="showData()">Click here</button>
[enter image description here][1]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbO4p.jpg)